# How to force Newtonsoft.Json.Net Dictionary to serialize as KeyValuePair

Tags: json.net

Is it possible to get Json.Net 4.5+ to serialize my Dictionary<,> as this;

```
{
    dic:[
        {k:"apples",v:2},
        {k:"pears",v:43}
    ]
}
```

as opposed to;

```
{
    dic:{
        "apples":2,
        "pears":43,
    }
}
```

Whilst the latter is a great default, and looking at the SO posts almost everyone wanted this when it wasn't the default, but I have one specific case when I actually want it the other (former) way instead. I tried adding the following to the dictionary class or member;

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType=typeof(DictionaryArrayConverter)]
```

But that just causes it to barf on a null in the serialization stack.